# 2016 Traverse-OBDII readiness check

Tags: chevrolet, ac, obd-ii, traverse

My air conditioner does not come on because I have a pin hole in the rear line. Will this affect performing a cycle to get the sensors to read

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What cycle are you trying to perform?

Comment: Which sensors are you trying to read?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

OBDII readiness checks have to do with emissions. To my knowledge, there is absolutely zero tie-in between the readiness checks and the AirCon unit in the vehicle.